# How can I access OnVelocityChange Event?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have some **parameter** (*rigidbody.velocity*)

I need to track this, and, if the parameter is changed, some action must be doing.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your question has a very simple answer. Whenever you change this variable in your code, you can call the change event. In fact, a function similar to Property. But since your variable is `rb.velocity` and you want to check its change. As below, record the previous frame value and check it with the current value before resetting.

*Note that velocity in 2D is Vector2D.*

```cs
private Vector3 lastVelocity; // cache previous frame rb.velocity
public void Update()
{
    if (rb.velocity != lastVelocity)
    {
        OnVeloictyChange(rb.velocity-lastVelocity);
    }
    
    lastVelocity = rb.velocity;
}

private void OnVeloictyChange(Vector3 delta)
{
     // value is changed This Frame, So Event code is here
}
```

Comment: I don't like this hammering, I mean, it's a non-necessary checker that is being done at each frame, but its easier to use

Comment: @Nefisto Do you know that rigidBody velocity in Unity changes with in-game physical reactions? Therefore, because of the complex implementation of your method for newbies, your event does not work properly and it also has Allocation. In general, don't worry about the few nanoseconds of vector checking in 2023, this code solves the OP's problem. ;)

Comment: I'ts not just the nanoseconds, it also about DRY, changing velocity isn't a thing that u normally do directly, what normally happens is asking to changes through API's that will then touch the velocity, in ur sample who should keep asking to unity when velocity has been updated? I'm saying this because I will probably wanna register some external updates to an specific component? and if we scale it? multiple components checking a value change? to which one of them we should register, IMO this approach make things harder on long run, its just simple to implement in a first moment

Comment: @KiynL the allocation in the other answer is on the stack; it's irrelevant from a perf standpoint. @Nefisto, the check every frame here is effectively noise for perf. If you're doing this 100k times per frame then, yes, it'll be an issue. I have yet to see the Unity title where an `if` is a perf bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a property of a third library (in this case unity) you can't simply add something to track it, what you can do instead is create a layer that will pass the information to a rigid body and trigger the events that you wish before or after doing it, something on this line. Then u need to make sure that all changes in velocity pass through this class

```
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
    public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private new Rigidbody rigidbody;
        private Rigidbody Rigidbody => rigidbody == null
            ? rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
            : rigidbody;

        public event Action<(Vector3 oldValue, Vector3 newValue)> OnChangingRigidbodyVelocity;
        public event Action<Vector3> OnChangedRigidbodyVelocity;
        
        public Vector3 Velocity
        {
            get => Rigidbody.velocity;
            set
            {
                var oldValue = Rigidbody.velocity;
                OnChangingRigidbodyVelocity?.Invoke((oldValue, value));
                Rigidbody.velocity = value;
                OnChangedRigidbodyVelocity?.Invoke(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify this a bit by setting `.rigidbody` in the `Reset()` method.

Comment: @3Dave Will it add the component from the required component first or reset it first? But you are right, as it is a required component we don't need to have a lazy getter for it

Comment: The `RequiredComponentAttribute` will ensure that the component is added to the gameObject. `Reset()` can then find it and wire everything up.

Comment: Reset happens when u add a component or call it through context, for this reason I asked what will happen first, if reset goes first the component would not been added yet

Comment: Reset happens *after* the component has been created. This is the way we handle things internally.

Comment: When in doubt, test.